# How can I log into Google APIs on Android when I'm using Firebase AuthUI?

Tags: android, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

So, I've implemented Firebase Auth & AuthUI and successfully used the Google auth provider to log in a user. 
However, now I'm trying to access the Google APIs but I'm getting a login error when I try to access them. Code below is attempting to connect to Google Fit.

```
val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(requireContext(), fitnessOptions)
        Fitness.getHistoryClient(requireContext(), account)
                .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .addOnSuccessListener { r ->
                    val first = r.dataPoints.first()
                    ...
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    ...
                }
```

at which point I'm getting an error message of:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: The user must be signed in to make this API call.
```

I've debugged the Firebase Auth process and can see that there are two providers on the current `FirebaseUser`, one Google & one Firebase which looks like rather than authing my app with Google, Firebase is authing itself, then authing my app with Firebase.

I'm pretty sure I can remove AuthUI and manually do the Google SSO implementation (per Google's docs) but I *really* don't want to as I plan on having pretty much all the Auth providers enabled and I don't want to have to code them all manually (not to mention doing all the layout etc)

So, if anyone knows how to access the Google APIs/signed in Google Account from the Firebase authed user, I'd love to hear it!

Thanks in advance for any help you can render!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Firebase doesn't pass any default scopes to the Google sign in provider. Fixed it by doing

```
...
AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder()
    .setScopes(listOf(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ)
...
```

to access the standard steps read information. You can find out which scopes you need [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) and reverse-engineer it's name in the `Scopes` class from there.

Hope that helps!